# Translate C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have method SwitchScreen to change userControl. I want change my app from C# to VB. I tried to find on google but no result. Can someone help? :(

here is my method:

```
 public void SwitchScreen(object sender, string getText)
    {
        var screen = (UserControl)sender;
        headerTitle.Text = getText;

        if ((screen) != null)
        {
            StackPanelMain.Children.Clear();
            StackPanelMain.Children.Add(screen);
        }
    }
```

i've tried like this in VB:

```
 Public Sub SwitchScreen(sender As Object, getText As String)

    Dim Screen = sender(UserControl)
    headerTitle.Text = getText

    If (Screen Is Nothing) Then
        StackPanelMain.Children.Clear()
        StackPanelMain.Children.Add(Screen)
    End If
End Sub
```

But error on Dim Screen = sender(UserControl), 'UserControl' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: change to `Dim Screen as Object` , and in next line `Set Screen = CType(sender, UserControl)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing the meaning of that line when you write it that way.

C#

```
        var screen = (UserControl)sender;
```

This is taking the 'sender' var, casting as a 'UserControl' class, and setting to be referenced by the 'screen' var.

VB

```
    Dim Screen = sender(UserControl)
```

It's been  a while since I worked in VB, but it looks like you're calling a function named 'Sender' and passing 'UserControl' as a parameter, which it is not.

you need to find the VB equivilent of 'cast as Object' for your sender var.

Maybe

```
Dim Screen = CType(sender, UserControl)
```

Comment: I think either `CType` or `DirectCast` would work.  I think the latter is closer to an exact translation, though in this case I don't think the differences would matter as there won't be any accessible conversion operations.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Public Sub SwitchScreen(sender As Object, getText As String)

    Dim Screen as UserControl = sender
    headerTitle.Text = getText

    If (Screen IsNot Nothing) Then
        StackPanelMain.Children.Clear()
        StackPanelMain.Children.Add(Screen)
    End If
End Sub
```

vb should auto cast - a cast probably not required.

Comment: This will only work if `Option Strict On` is not used, which is not recommended.

Comment: Gee, that's a difficult call. With the rise of JavaScript, and boatloads of scripting environments and in fact MOST web based software? (including use of xml and json data), then forcing strong typing is kind of leaving our industry, and just about all systems quite much have gone down this road.  I'm open to both view points on this matter. One of the BIG reasons why I like asp.net is that we can write a lot of the server side code in a great language like c#, or vb. I really do have a dislike for say JavaScript.  But, I also quite much do accept a good deal of auto casting.

Comment: Our major vb applications (desktop and web) were built Option Strict Off. Can't say downsides (bugs from this choice) have existed or bitten us much. Benefits outweighed the downsides. One's mileage may vary on this issue.  This may well due to re-purpose boatloads of VB and VBA code(but was still better choice). Web based trends are towards "more lose" typing, and auto casting. In desktop software, c++ and even some c# developers would cringe in web land with so much lose scripting languages and systems in use today. But I 100% respect your advice - and it is good advice for readers here.

Comment: In my opinion, `Option Infer On` gives most of the benefits of more dynamic typing without any of the drawbacks, but YMMV.  There are some places where IMO `Option Strict On` is absolutely required because you can get silent bugs otherwise: anywhere you do something keyed on a delegate type and may later need to get the same item back.  Without strict, the "relaxed delegate convention" can let you subscribe to an event without the ability to unsubscribe.  Most things in strict can be individually toggled as warnings or errors, but I didn't find any way to do it with this.

Comment: Beyond that, I find that usually having it vs. not having it mostly catches silly things like accidentally omitting a function return type.  There are, admittedly, a few times when it ends up forcing me into explicitly writing out type conversion ceremony, but I find this is relatively rare in well-written code.  I do maintain some code bases written without strict, and I will leave it off in those in most cases because it becomes a major pain to add in all the necessary conversions due to type sloppiness (judgment on my code, not necessarily yours).

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Sub SwitchScreen(sender As Object, getText As String)

    Dim Screen As UserControl = TryCast(sender, UserControl)
    headerTitle.Text = getText

    If (Screen IsNot Nothing) Then
        StackPanelMain.Children.Clear()
        StackPanelMain.Children.Add(Screen)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `TryCast` is the VB equivalent to C#'s `as`.  This way of doing things will work for the non-failure case, but the failure case will convert an InvalidCastException to a NullReferenceException.  Personally, I'd rather use a throwing conversion so that I get a more descriptive error (or else explicitly test for failure of the cast).

Comment: Sure, I actually find in 99% of cases, auto casting is fine, and in fact being forced to deal with most simple default castings all day long is a pain in c#. I did a good stint in writing Pascal applications, so I do come from a background in which I tend to prefer STRONG types in my applications. So, EVEN with my penchant for preferring strong typed coding environments? I still enjoy and use and in fact like the auto casting that vb gives me. Like all good developers, one learns when auto casting is  bad idea, and that auto casting provides far more benefits then downsides- but with caution!

Comment: Having said a above? I up-voted your  comment, since a throwing conversion is without question the best advice here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal FWIW my comment here was only as to the specific use of `TryCast` in this answer.

Comment: Your advice applies in general - but fair enough - my apologies for swaying this thread and scope of this issue and your simple suggest.